# Swift 3 #selector and type names

Tags: swift, selector, swift3

Just updated to Xcode8 with Swift 3.  Unfortunately, I am unable to add a target to a button where the target refers to a function in another class.

```
class AddToDoViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIButton!
  var st : SelectorTest!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      st = SelectorTest()

      st.didTapButtonHandler = {
        self.doneButton.isSelected = !self.doneButton.isSelected
        print("self.doneButton.selected=\(self.doneButton.isSelected)")
      }

      doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SelectorTest.didTapTheButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
  }
}


class SelectorTest {
    typealias ToDoCellDidTapButtonHandler = () -> Void
    var didTapButtonHandler: ToDoCellDidTapButtonHandler?

    @objc func didTapTheButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let handler = didTapButtonHandler {
            handler()
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the target is SelectorTest.didTapButton(_:) which exists in the SelectorTest class.  However when I run and click on the button I get a runtime error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[Done.AddToDoViewController didTapTheButton:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Since I configured the target on the button to point to

```
SelectorTest.didTapTheButton(_:)
```

which definitely exists, why am I getting a runtime error stating that it cannot find `didTapTheButton(_:)` on the AddToDoViewController?  Especially when I did not specify `AddToDoViewController.didTapTheButton(_:)` as the target?

```
Done.AddToDoViewController didTapTheButton:
```

I am wondering if the `#selector` ignores the class name and assumes that the target is on the class that added the target to the button (AddToDoViewController)?

How can I set the target to `SelectorTest.didTapTheButton(_:)` and at runtime have the `SelectorTest.didTapTheButton(_:)` execute instead of the runtime attempting to fire the `AddToDoViewController.didTapTheButton(_:)` which is not the configured target and doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the object of `SelectorTest` class with `addTarget` instead of `self`.

```
doneButton.addTarget(st, action: #selector(SelectorTest.didTapTheButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

In `addTarget` first parameter target is type of `Any?`

> The target object is the object whose action method is called. If you specify nil, UIKit searches the responder chain for an object that responds to the specified action message and delivers the message to that object.

Comment: Thanks, I would think that you would get a compile time error since self and SelectorTest do not resolve to the same class.

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: If in AddToDoViewController: addTarget(self, action: #selector(SelectorTest.didTapTheButton(_:)...  I wish that I could get a compile time error/warning since self != SelectorTest.  If you specify self, it ignores the class type in the #selector.